# Is there any way to extract all the api requests in an excel or pdf file made in last 7 days under application insights transaction search?

Tags: azure-api-management

I basically want to export the details of all api requests made in last 7 days in an excel or pdf file from azure application insights.

I tried to copy link option available under transaction search section.

Comment: Did you try the export button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click `Export` and select `Open in Excel`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Markus Meyer , I can view this under Logs section.